# How do I make a div width depending on the viewport space that is left

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive-design

Please have a look at the Wireframe I created to see what I am trying to achieve.
I have created 2 screens so you can see the desired behavior depending on different screen sizes.

**[Wireframe Link](https://xd.adobe.com/view/8fba63c3-fb30-431c-a797-f3b8032a171d-dae9/specs/)**

I basically want to have a center-aligned container "Main-Section" with a max-width (depending on screen size) and a 12col grid inside. To the left and right of the container should then be two divs "Left/Right Lane", which share the remaining space/width on each side.

My main question:
**How do I set up the left/right lanes so that they occupy the rest of the screen-width evenly?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

your question does not includes code.
If you have a low level of technical capabilities, I would suggest you to use the Bootstrap Grid System.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/
If you are a beginner it is a good practice to read docs and understand it.

Comment: I am not really asking for code. It is more the idea of what needs to be done. Does the div need to be set to a specific position, min-width, percentage etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found the answer myself. The important piece of information I was missing was:

flex-grow

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}


.left-col, .right-col {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.center-col {
  width: 500px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Hangtime/L86wkce7/1/